# RegularExpressionValidator to limit input length and allow empty strings

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex

I'm really bad with regex and was looking at another question almost identical to this but can't get it to work as I need.

I was to use a RegularExpressionValidator that will allow any character up to 255 characters or nothing at all. I tried,

```
ValidateExpression="^.{255}$"
```

but it throws an unhanded exception when the textbox that I'm checking is empty.

I've also tried

```
ValidateExpression="^.{,255}$"
```

Thank you
Rodney

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `^.{0,255}$`? Not sure what exception you are getting though.

EDIT: Also, if struggling with .Net regex, [Regex Hero tester](http://regexhero.net/tester/) is a great help. I know there are other sites, but this one is by far the best, if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

The proper expression is `^.{0,255}$`.

`^.{255}$` will only match if there is exactly 255 characters, while `^.{,255}$` will match the literal string "{,255}".

If there are still issues after trying that, can you tell us the exception?

Comment: I've tried ^.{0,255}$, and it still is failing. I'm getting the following exception:  Inner exception message: The ControlToValidate property of 'tbSubGoalText_RegularExpressionValidator' cannot be blank. Exception message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. When the page first displays it will always be empty...

Comment: I got past the Exception, but it still doesn't appear to be matching correctly.

Comment: I think I got it. It appears to be working. Actually user error on my part. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If it throws an `HttpRequestValidationException` exception, you can use the members of the [`UnvalidatedRequestValues` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.unvalidatedrequestvalues(v=vs.110).aspx).

Mind that "Validation succeeds if the input control is empty" ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator(v=vs.140).aspx)). You may add a `RequiredFieldValidator` field to ensure that the user does not leave a text box blank (if you use the `RequiredFieldValidator` control inside an `UpdatePanel` control, make sure that the validator control and the control it is associated with are in the same panel - [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
<asp:textbox id="myTB" 
  runat="Server">
</asp:textbox>
//  ... MAKE SURE YOU DO NOT USE TextMode="Number"!!!
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator
           ID="Value1RequiredValidator"
           ControlToValidate="myTB"
           ErrorMessage="Please enter a number.<br />"
           Display="Dynamic"
           runat="server"/>
```

And as for regex, `^.{255}$` means ***match any character (except newline) exactly 255 times between string start and end***. I think it makes sense to allow `^[1-9][0-9]{0,254}$` (for values like '34', '104', etc.).